# Reuse PDE' s ManifestEditor and meet NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde, pde

1.what we are planning to do :

Reuse the `ManifestEditor` to open the `MANIFEST.MF` file, and add our features to the first OverviewPage.

2.what we already have known and done :

It's dangerous to use the internal classes and APIs, so we create a ManifestEditorNew which extends ManifestEditor.

```
import org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.editor.plugin.ManifestEditor;
import org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.editor.plugin.OverviewPage;

public class TheNewManifestEditor extends ManifestEditor{

    //it's strange that the default fist page is not the OverviewPage,so we override this method
    @Override
    protected String computeInitialPageId() {
        return OverviewPage.PAGE_ID;
    }
}
```

3.what Exception we meet :

The NullPointerException.
Once our `TheNewManifestEditor` gained focus, the give us an NPE, but we can not find ant clues which caused this.
[image]

Comment: You are still using internal classes, just extending the class does not help. These internal classes can and do change between releases sometimes even disappearing altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to called `super.computeInitialPageId()` because it looks like it does some set up.

Note: The reason the overview page is not always shown is because the editor remembers the the last page you looked at and shows you that. It will default to the overview page the first time the manifest is edited.

Just extending an internal class does not remove the fact that you are using internal Eclipse classes which violates the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-API-Use/index.html). Internal classes can and do change and sometimes even disappear altogether, you are likely to have a lot of trouble when moving between Eclipse releases.

Comment: So in my condition should I re-write a new editor? We just wanna do some simple changes in the `OverViewPage`. Building a new editor will cost too much efforts.Any advice ?

Comment: I can't see any 'official' interfaces in to the manifest editor so it is either write your own editor or take a risk - but I have seen questions here where people have had big problems updating their code to a new release because internal classes have had big changes.